# Getting user ID in TwitchIO

Tags: python, bots, twitch

I'm writing a Twitch bot. I'd like to be able to store ranking of number of comments posted. So I'd like to label users by their Twitch ID in DB.

I wrote this get function :

```
  5 def getId(chatter : Union[twitchio.Chatter, twitchio.PartialChatter]):                                                                                                                               
  6     if isinstance(chatter,twitchio.chatter.Chatter):                            
  7                                                                                 
  8         userVar = chatter.channel.user()                                        
  9         print("NormalChatter", type(userVar))                                   
 10                                                                                 
 11         return userVar                                                          
 12         #return chatter.channel.user().id                                       
 13         #return chatter.id                                                      
 14                                                                                 
 15     elif isinstance(chatter, twitchio.PartialChatter):                          
 16         return chatter.user().id                                                
 17     else:                                                                       
 18         print("NoneBoy")
```

While getting chatters from Channel object I end up with Chatter object as tested by print in line 9. Chatter object should have "id" attribute as per [https://twitchio.dev/en/stable/reference.html#twitchio.Chatter]
It has the attribute, but he attribute is NULL.

I tried to get ID by using channel and "user()" coroutine, but it seems like it does not return anything other than itself (chatter.channel.user().id causes 'AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'id' ') I did it because I thought maybe it's some inheritance from PartialChatter obj.

Does anyone knows how to get this user ID ?

Comment: if it is a coroutine, you need to `await` it first

Comment: It works, but apparently the through the channel.user() I get (unsuprisingly )the ID of the owner of a stream, while I need the ID of the chatters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The userID is not something every developer can access and Twitch gives it sparsely. The best way to serialize users is by user name.

This is the answer I got from discord server for Twitch APIs in TwitchIO thread.